# php - how to get meta tags from url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to get meta tags from url. If there is a data attribute value, it cannot be extracted properly. How do I change the regular expression?

HTML Code

```
1. <meta property="og:title" content="111">
2. <meta data-one="true" property="og:description" content="222">
3. <meta data-two="true" property="og:image" content="333">
4. <meta data-three="true" data-another="true" property="og:url" content="444">
```

PHP Code

```
preg_match_all('~<\s*meta\s*property="(og:[^"]+)"\s*content="([^"]*)~i', $html, $matches);
```

Result

```
Array(
  [0] => og:title
)
```

Hope Result

```
Array(
  [0] => og:title,
  [1] => og:description,
  [2] => og:image,
  [3] => og:url
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the second and third `\s*` which says to match zero or more spaces. However, in the second case you want to match `\b.*\b`, word boundary (end of `meta`), then anything, then a new word boundary (start of `property`). For the third case, `\s.*\b` is needed as `"` is not a word boundary, so your fixed regex is:

```
preg_match_all('~<\s*meta\b.*\bproperty="(og:[^"]+)"\s.*\bcontent="([^"]*)~i', $html, $matches);
```

See [the example here](https://regex101.com/r/v95ibU/1).